# PyTorch GPU memory leak during inference

Tags: nlp, pytorch, gpu, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to encode documents sentence-wise with a huggingface transformer module. I'm using the very small `google/bert_uncased_L-2_H-128_A-2` pretrained model with the following code:

```
def pre_encode_wikipedia(model, tokenizer, device, save_path):
  
  document_data_list = []

  for iteration, document in enumerate(wikipedia_small['text']):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    sentence_embeds_per_doc = [torch.randn(128)]
    attention_mask_per_doc = [1]
    special_tokens_per_doc = [1]

    doc_split = nltk.sent_tokenize(document)
    doc_tokenized = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(doc_split, padding='longest', truncation=True, max_length=512, return_tensors='pt')

    for key, value in doc_tokenized.items():
      doc_tokenized[key] = doc_tokenized[key].to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():  
      doc_encoded = model(**doc_tokenized)

    for sentence in doc_encoded['last_hidden_state']:
      sentence[0].to('cpu')
      sentence_embeds_per_doc.append(sentence[0])
      attention_mask_per_doc.append(1)
      special_tokens_per_doc.append(0)

    sentence_embeds = torch.stack(sentence_embeds_per_doc)
    attention_mask = torch.FloatTensor(attention_mask_per_doc)
    special_tokens_mask = torch.FloatTensor(special_tokens_per_doc)

    document_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(*[sentence_embeds, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask])
    torch.save(document_data, f'{save_path}{time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")}{iteration}.pt')
    print(f"Document at {iteration} encoded and saved.")
```

After about 200-300 iterations on my local GTX 1060 3GB I get an error saying that my **CUDA memory is full**. Running this code on Colab with more GPU RAM gives me a few thousand iterations.

Things I've tried:

- Adding `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` to the start of every iteration to clear out previously held tensors
- Wrapping the model in `torch.no_grad()` to disable the computation graph
- Setting `model.eval()` to disable any stochastic properties that might take up memory
- Sending the output straight to CPU in hopes to free up memory

I'm baffled as to why my memory keeps overflowing. I've trained several models of bigger sizes, applying all the standard practices of a training loop (`optimizer.zero_grad()`, etc.) I've never had this problem. Why does it appear during this seemingly trivial task?

**Edit #1**
Changing `sentence[0].to('cpu')` to `cpu_sentence = sentence[0].to('cpu')` gave me a few thousand iterations before VRAM usage suddenly spiked, causing the run to crash:[image]

Comment: I don't think `sentence[0].to('cpu')` will move your tensor to `'cpu'`, it will make a copy. Could you check?

Comment: How do I check whether it's making a copy or not?

Comment: Do you get this error also on CUDA after the few 1000 iterations?

Comment: Yes same error, I'm assuming it's just because the Colab GPUs have larger VRAM and it takes more iterations to fill up

Answer (score 2):

Can you try replacing

```
sentence[0].to('cpu')
```

with

```
cpu_sentence = sentence[0].to('cpu')
```

See more info here https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to

Comment: This seemed to work at first VRAM was reasonable low utilization for a few thousand iterations now. About an order of magnitude more than what I would usually get so something definitely worked but then ```RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 112.00 MiB (GPU 0; 3.00 GiB total capacity; 1.95 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 1.98 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)``` reappeared. I'm posting a picture of the VRAM spike in the description.

Comment: Did you change it like this:
      cpu_sentence = sentence[0].to('cpu')
      sentence_embeds_per_doc.append(cpu_sentence)

Comment: I did, yes. Got any other idea what I could try?

Comment: I think you should look into what allocates this much memory: 112.00 MiB

Comment: When you import the pretrained model you can do the following:
model = ???.from_pretrained("google/bert_uncased_L-2_H-128_A-2")
model.to("cpu)

Comment: Computing on CPU works, it's painfully slow but not a neck breaker because this routine is only part of my preprocessing. I'm still seeing the spikes in RAM usage but it doesn't crash because memory swapping kicks in, that doesn't work for VRAM though. I'm fairly certain that the dataset contains a few very disproportionately large documents that suddenly consume the memory.